# Polynomial expression proof

Tags: proof-verification

[image]

I have been trying to solve this proof posted on  my timeline but I am stuck - I am not a mathematician but computer scientist, and I could do with some hints or on what attack to take or rules that would help me do it for myself.Proofs are my sticking point.

1) rules to eliminate X ,Cos and Sin for example? What kind of proof?

Comment: It should have asked "prove or disprove".

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random equation. You can take particualr values of $x$ and $y$ and can verify that this equation does not holds. For instance take $x= \pi$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: a proof by calculation - but isn't this for only one case not all cases?

Comment: You can verify it for different values of $x$ and $y$ as well.

Comment: Basically, if an equation is true, it must be true for all values of $x$ and $y$.